# Multiple simultaneous SELECT statements in MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, mysql-connector

I'm trying to get a snapshot of what has been changed between two times in a MySQL database. I have a number of tables of different entities, and each table has a "Last Updated" column which is automatically set to the current date when a row is updated.

I have a client app which queries the database, using multiple SELECT statements (one for each table in the database), for any rows which have: "App's Previous Sync Time" <= "Last Updated" < "Current System Time". This is working fine, and successfully keeps the client app in sync with the database. However, some of the tables have relationships between them, and I'm worried that each SELECT statement is not run at the same time on the database, so I might end up with something like this:

```
Client App              |            Server App
SELECT * FROM Table1    |
                        |       Update Table1 & Table2, altering relationships
SELECT * FROM Table2    |
```

So that the tables (and relationships) are modified mid way through taking the snapshot, potentially returning some invalid relationship information (e.g. The server app inserts new rows into tables 1 & 2, so when the client queries table 2, there is a row that references an entry in table 1 that doesn't exist).

I think I need to use either transactions or locking, but I'm not sure which or if there's a better way. I'm using the MySQL Connector/.NET to access the server from C#. Currently, I create a single MySQLCommand, with all the SELECT statements in, e.g.:

```
string commandString = "SELECT * FROM Table1; SELECT * FROM Table2;";
using (MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(commandString, connection))
```

Then read them all with:

```
 using (MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
 {
     do
     {
        if (reader.HasRows)
        {
             //....
        }         
     } while (reader.NextResult());
 }
```

How would I go about preventing the tables being modified between SELECT statements?

Comment: Have you tried LOCK and UNLOCK TABLES

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/lock-tables.html

Comment: So would I do something like: LOCK TABLES Table1 READ, Table2 READ; SELECT * FROM Table1; SELECT * FROM Table2; UNLOCK TABLES; ? And this would prevent writes to those tables from other connections? What happens if someone tries to write while it's locked? Does it just wait or does it cause an error?

Comment: It would generate a lock error.  You might want to perform this operation in a testing environment first and then make a backup before you do it live.  Whatever you do 1) BACKUP first 2) Test Environment if possible.

Comment: A table lock protects only against inappropriate reads or writes by other sessions. The session holding the lock, even a read lock, can perform table-level operations such as DROP TABLE. Truncate operations are not transaction-safe, so an error occurs if the session attempts one during an active transaction or while holding a table lock.

Answer (score 0):

You should use transaction. Not on client app, but on server app.

```
begin transaction
update table1 set ....
update table2 set ....
update table2 set ....
commit
```

this way, table1 and table2 committed simultaneously, ensuring consistent read on client apps.

Note: you have to use InnoDB engine for transaction to work